# Update specific rows and columns without creating duplictes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to overwrite/update some values in some rows. That is the initial data

```
   Foo Bar  vals
0    0   a     0
1    1   b     1
2    2   c     2
3    3   d     3
4    4   e     4
```

I want to give `Foo` `2` and `4` new `vals`. This is the expected output.

```
   Foo Bar  vals
0    0   a     0
1    1   b     1
2    2   c    78
3    3   d     3
4    4   e    63
```

But that code using `DataFrame.update()` doesn't work that way and does create duplicated lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': range(5), 'Bar': list('abcde'), 'vals': range(5)})
print(df)

df.update(
    pd.DataFrame({'Foo': [2, 4], 'vals': [78, 63]})
)

print(df)
```

The result is

```
   Foo Bar  vals
0  2.0   a  78.0
1  4.0   b  63.0
2  2.0   c   2.0
3  3.0   d   3.0
4  4.0   e   4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
update_from = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': [2, 4], 'vals': [78, 63]})
m = df['Foo'].isin(update_from['Foo'])
df.loc[m, 'vals'] = df.loc[m, 'Foo'].map(update_from.set_index('Foo')['vals'])
```

output:

```
   Foo Bar  vals
0    0   a     0
1    1   b     1
2    2   c    78
3    3   d     3
4    4   e    63
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter your `Foo` series with [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and set the values with lists.

**NB.** this method does not check for order, only membership. Use [@SomeDude's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73918964/17676984) if order matters.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': range(5), 'Bar': list('abcde'), 'vals': range(5)})

df.loc[df["Foo"].isin([2, 4]), "vals"] = [78, 63]
print(df)
```

gives

```
   Foo Bar  vals
0    0   a     0
1    1   b     1
2    2   c    78
3    3   d     3
4    4   e    63
```

Comment: This won't work if you interchange rows with index 2, 4. because .isin doesn't check for order, it just checks membership.

Comment: @SomeDude, you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['old value'],'new value')
```

what I mean is

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': range(5), 'Bar': list('abcde'), 'vals':range(5)})

print(df)

df['vals'] = df['vals'].replace([2],[78])

df['vals'] = df['vals'].replace([4],[63])

print(df) # which prints your desired output
```